# How can I send an event from a component to its parent multiple times?

Tags: java, zk

I am building on my earlier question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58537258/how-can-i-pass-on-the-oncheck-event-of-a-checkbox-to-its-parent-in-zk):

I have a vbox with some checkboxes in it that are added dynamically by the viewmodel of the overall window. The viewmodel registers a listener to the onCheck event of the checkbox as follows:

```
if (childName.equals("org.zkoss.zul.Checkbox")) {
    child.addEventListener(1000,"onCheck", new EventListener<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
            Events.postEvent(1000,"onSelectionChange",parent,null);                     
        }                       
    });
}
```

The onSelectionChange event is caught in the parent vbox like so:

```
<vbox onSelectionChange="@command('onChange', component=self, finishButton=finish)"/>
```

The entire vbox component is part of a wizard that allows for going back and forth among its pages. The vbox component can therefore be displayed multiple times. The first time, the onSelectionChange event is properly fired and caught by the vbox component. Thus, onChange is correctly called. The second time the component is loaded, however, the event is fired by the checkboxes, but not caught by the vbox.

I have experimented with postEvent as well as sendEvent. The event is not correctly forwarded to the parent vbox in any case. Does anyone have an idea why this is so?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you and the radioboxes with code? You can do that also in the zul with children attributen and then forward the onCheck event to the vbox

Comment: Hi @chillworld, thanks for your comment. I know your solution is possible. However, this is not my use case. I am developing a wizard API. A wizard has a "frame" with back, next and finish buttons. Inside the frame, is the wizard page content which is essentially a grid with rows containing a label and a widget. I cannot make any assumptions as to the content of these wizard pages. The pages are build dynamically by the wizard viewmodel based on some input the API gets from its user. If radioboxes are included on the wizard page, the viewmodel has to add them to it. Hope, that clarifies it.

Comment: Because there is no answer yet, did you check with developer tools if the events are actually fired?

Comment: I am sure all you describe is possible, however in order debug and eventually suggest something the provided code is not sufficient. Can you provide something runnable e.g. on http://zkfiddle.org/ highlighting your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a runnable example (based on what I understood from your descriptions), which works ... 
http://zkfiddle.org/sample/51j1be/1-wizard-checkboxes-custom-events

Maybe that helps as a template for your scenario. If not you can adjust and save it to show your problem. So I can have another look.

Comment: Hi Cor, thank you so much. I will try it out, once I am back from vacation.... :)